# How to make a customize column's button in SharePoint library visible only when File type is "Folder"

Tags: json, sharepoint, office365, power-automate

I have a customized button column  (Test)

I would like to set condition for the button to be shown when the file type = folder only.
Below is my Json code but unfortunately it doesn't works.

```
  {
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": 
{
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"\"}"


  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "color": "#0078d7",
    "cursor": "pointer",
"display": "=if(  ([$Type] == 'Folder' ), 'block', 'none')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "FollowUser"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "6px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "click to start"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a content type column in SharePoint Library, you can judge the value of this column to determine whether to display this button.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": 
{
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"\"}"


  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "color": "#0078d7",
    "cursor": "pointer",
"display": "=if(  ([$ContentType] == 'Folder' ), 'block', 'none')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "FollowUser"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "6px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "click to start"
    }
  ]
}
```

Test result:
[image]